# Linq: Handle empty table

Tags: linq

How do you handle an empty table/NullReference in LINQ?

I have the following Linq statement in my code:

```
List<FeaturedTrack> features = _db.FeaturedTracks.Where(f => (f.FeatureStartDate >= DateTime.Now && f.FeatureEndDate <= DateTime.Now) ||
                                                                     (f.FeatureStartDate == null && f.FeatureEndDate == null))
                                                             .ToList<FeaturedTrack>();
```

My table is currently empty, now I know this table won't be empty but it got me wondering about how to handle the NullReference error in case it is.

I've tried this:

```
int test = _db.FeaturedTracks.Count();
if (test > 0)
{
   ...
}
```

However my code breaks on the first line, so how do I check the table is empty before running the statement?

Comment: It doesn't look like the error has anything to do with the table being empty: the "plain" `int test = _db.FeaturedTracks.Count();` should have succeeded. I think that once you figure out what's the problem with the count, it will no longer be necessary, because your first snippet looks correct.

Comment: Sorry, by break I meant it gives me a NullReferenceException Error.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight seems you're right.. I put in a record and it's still breaking with a NullReferenceException... now I'm extremely confused.

Comment: Alright looks like I figured it out. I screwed up my DbContext declaration in my controller.